# Is there a way to identify exchanges in the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, exchanges

Is there a way to identify transactions that occur on exchanges (such as Mt. Gox) in the blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on the above answer, blockchain.info provides information about several APis and exchanges here: 
https://blockchain.info/api/3rd_party_apis

Answer (score 0):

You can likely get a lot of trade information directly from the [MTGox API](https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview), and match results up with the blockchain if needed.